# Activerecord unknown column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on someone else's code. They have a column in the Account table called "type" that records what type of account the user has (paid, free etc). Now, I'm trying to make a db call via active record like so:

```
<%= Account.count(:conditions => ["type = ?", "AccountDemo" ]) %>
```

however, it is telling me the column is not found. Is that because he used the word "type" and that is not allowed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the application you inherited using Single Table Inheritance?  If that's the case, then I'd be looking at AccountDemo.count, and not working off the superclass...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"type" is a special column name that is generally used with Single Table Inheritance.  If you are not using STI, then the first thing you should do is to rename that column.  If you are using STI, then you should be doing

```
AccountDemo.count
```

rather than working with the superclass directly.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know you could do that. How do I know when I can just call AccountDemo.count vs. the other way? Also, I have AccountFree and AccountPaid as well. It is weird that rails automatically knows which table i'm calling that on, how does it know that?

Comment: Search for Single Table Inheritance rails and you'll get a far better answer than I can cram into a comment.  Just to confirm, are there classes (AccountDemo, AccountFree, AccountPaid) that all inherit from Account (which inherits from ActiveRecord)?  If there are not, then what I suggested won't work.  If they are there, then rails is just managing the subclass through the "type" column, and it is all taken care of for you.  When you call a method on the subclass, rails automatically looks for records in the superclass of the appropriate type.

Comment: Yes, it works great..thank you. Quick follow up question - there's another column for Account called users_count. When I do AccountPro.users_count it says undefined method "users_count". I want to sum up all the users_counts that exist for AccountPros..is that possible?

Comment: Is there a User model that has an ActiveRecord association with Account?  It seems a little odd to store this directly in the database, since that will force you to go directly to the Accounts column and update the number each time you add or remove a user.  Are you looking to get the total users associated with all of your AccountPro objects, or are you looking for the number of users associated with a particular AccountPro?

Comment: found something that works: AccountDemo.sum(:users_count)

pretty simple. the User model belongs to Account but the code stores a users_count column in the Account table. Not sure why but someone wrote this code previously. I'm sure there's a good reason.